# Unable to pass parameters to a perl script inside a bash script

Tags: bash

I would like to pass parameters to a perl script using positional parameters inside a bash script "tablecheck.sh". I am using an **alias "tablecheck" to call "tablecheck.sh"**.

```
#!/bin/bash
/scripts/tables.pl /var/lib/mysql/$1/ /var/mysql/$1/mysql.sock > /tmp/chktables_$1 2>&1 &
```

Perl script by itself works fine. But when I do "tablecheck MySQLinstance", $1 stays $1. It won't get replaced by the instance. So I get the output as follows:

```
Exit /scripts/tables.pl /var/lib/mysql/$1/ /var/mysql/$1/mysql.sock > /tmp/chktables_$1 2>&1 &
```

The job exits.

```
FYI: alias tablecheck='. pathtobashscript/tablecheck.sh'
```

I have a bunch of aliases in another bash script. Hence . command.

Could anyone help me... I have gone till the 3rd page of Google to find an answer. Tried so many things with no luck.

I am a noob. But may be it has something to do with it being a background job or $1 in a path... I don't understand why the $1 won't get replaced...

Comment: How are you invoking `tablecheck`? Post your script `tablecheck.sh`

Comment: It works fine for me, `$1` is well expanded by the shell.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
/scripts/tables.pl /var/lib/mysql/$1/ /var/mysql/$1/mysql.sock > /tmp/chktables_$1 2>&1 &

Comment: can you echo $1 in bash script? Cause $1 works fine for me

Comment: You probably do not want to use the `.` command to run the script.  It might work, but you probably should not be using it.

Comment: I have a bunch of aliases in another bash script. Hence . command.

Comment: user4035: Yes, I can echo $1. It won't work only when used as a parameter for perl script.

Comment: Please provide a minimal sh and Perl script that demonstrates the problem. I've just created a Perl script `myscript.perl` containing `print "$ARGV[0]\n"`, a bash script `myscript.bash` containing `./myscript.perl "$1"`, and an alias `alias myscript=". ./myscript.bash`". Running `myscript foo` prints `foo` just fine, so the problem must be something in your script. Please strip it down to the minimum length that still exhibits the misbehavior, and post it here.

Comment: I am a noob. But may be it has something to do with it being a background job or $1 in a path... I don't understand why the $1 won't get replaced...

Comment: are you sure you are using bash ?
maybe try running it is as 
$ bash myscript.bash something

Answer (score 1):

If I copy your exact set up (which I agree with other commenters, is some what unusual) then I believe I am getting the same error message

```
$ tablecheck foo
[1]+  Exit 127                /scripts/tables.pl /var/lib/mysql/$1/ /var/mysql/$1/mysql.sock > /tmp/chktables_$1 2>&1
```

In the /tmp/chktables_foo file that it makes there is an additional error message, in my case "bash: /scripts/tables.pl: No such file or directory"

I suspect permissions are wrong in your case